# jquery replace string from html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, str-replace

I am trying to replace a CSS style in the following code:

```
var theHTML = this.html();
theHTML.replace("style=\"display:none;\"", "style=\"display:inline;\"");
alert(theHTML);
```

The html looks like this:

```
<IMG SRC="picturesFromServer.asp?PhotoId=365481" style="display:none;">
```

However once i check to see if it changed it or not it keeps displaying none instead of inline. I'm just trying to make it visible before i print it.

Comment: *Why* does the HTML have `style="display:none;"` in the first place?

Comment: @Madmartigan: To hide the image from the user. Then it prints out. Hints thats why i want to show it before it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** If what you are trying to accomplish is, get the `img` tag inside `this` and append it somewhere else, with `display:none;` do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/tL3Uf/

HTML

```
​<div id="mainContainer">
    <img src="http://imgh.us/business-online.jpg" style="display:none;" /> </div>

​<div id="destination"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript

```
​$(function(){
    var $img = $("#mainContainer img").clone();
    $img.show(0).appendTo('#destination');
});​
```

CSS

```
#incase image doesnt load

img{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f00;        
}​
```

Comment: It's a bad solution to begin with, doing a string replace.

Comment: Did not work i am afraid. B. VB's suggestion **did work** though but didn't show the image when it was printed out.

Comment: @StealthRT i edited my answere. it works now. check the fiddle

Answer (score 6):

You could use JQuery's `.css()` method:

```
$("img").css("display","inline");
```

Comment: Meaning this.html().css("display","inline");?

Comment: @StealthRT this=> `$("img")` will select all image tags. You could give you image tag some id, lets say `<img id='target' ..` then you can use `$("#target")` to select that image. Are you looking to target ALL images or ALL tags in the whole document?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not a jQuery master, but in Javascript are strings immutable? Should you try something like

```
theHtml = theHtml.replace(...)
```

Comment: That worked but when i print it out it has no image so its still hidden :o(

Answer (score 0):

replace the first two lines of the given code with this line :

```
$(this).find("img").css("display","inline");
```

Comment: the html contains an image tag, and you want to change the display of that tag...I suggest go for the .css() instead of string replacement.

Comment: I agree. This is the nicest way to accomplish showing the image, taking advantage of what jQuery is good at.

Answer (score 0):

The string `.replace() method` doesn't update the string you call it on, it returns a new string - so that's why your `alert(theHTML)` continues to display the original string. If you said this:

```
theHTML = theHTML.replace("style=\"display:none;\"", "style=\"display:inline;\"")
```

Then `alert(theHTML)` would show the replaced version.

However, that still won't have any effect on the actual img element, because it is still just a manipulation of a string variable that has no connection to your element. To actually make the img element visible you'd have to replace it with a new element generated from your string, which is a hassle, or you can just set the `display` property directly:

```
$(this).css("display", "inline");
```

Note also that your original code said `this.html()` - it seems unlikely that `this` would be a jQuery object that you can call the jQuery `.html()` method on, it is more likely to be the DOM element itself in which case you'd need to say `$(this).html()`. So if any of the answers don't work it might be related to how you are getting the `this` reference to the img element in the first place - might be helpful if you could update your question to show that.

**Note also that if the idea here is for the img element to appear in printed output but not otherwise you can do that with CSS:**

```
@media all {
   img.printOnly { display: none; }
}
@media print {
   img.printOnly { display: inline; }
}
```

Give the "printOnly" class (or whatever classname you want to use) to any elements that should appear for print only. Or specify by id. Whatever.